# Sum of $n$ terms of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is the sum of $n$ terms of the series $${1\over(4\times 9)} + {1\over(9\times 14)} + {1\over(14\times 19)} + {1\over(19 \times 24)} +  ... ?$$ 
The answer is $n\over 4(5n+4)$, but I can't figure out the method to be used to reach that answer. 
The $n-th$ term of the series is $1\over{(5n-1)(5n+4)}$.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general term is

$${1\over (5k+4)(5k+9)}={1\over {5(5k+4)}}-{1\over {5(5k+9)}}$$

So the sum telescopes

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{1\over (5k+4)(5k+9)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{1\over {5(5k+4)}}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{1\over{5(5k+9)}}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{1\over {5(5k+4)}}-\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over{5(5k+4)}}\\&={1\over 20}-{1\over{5(5n+4)}}\\&={5n+4-4\over {20(5n+4)}}\\&={n\over{4(5n+4)}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$\frac{1}{(5n-1)(5n+4)}=\frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{1}{5n-1}-\frac{1}{5n+4} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{(5n+4)(5n+9)}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{5n+4}-\frac{1}{5n+9}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5N+9}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$\frac{1}{(5n+4)(5n+9)}=\frac{1}{5}(\frac{1}{5n+4}-\frac{1}{5n+9})$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(5n-1)(5n+4)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{1}{5n-1}-\frac{1}{5n+4} \right)=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac{1}{5n-1} -\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{5n+4} $$
$$=\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }  \frac{1}{5n-1} -\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{5n+4}$$
$$=\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac{1}{5n+4} -\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{5n+4}$$
$$=\frac{1}{20}$$